# Laravel How to solve SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY' error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a Seeder in my `laravel`-application where I try to do the following:

```
DB::table('users_roles')->insert([
   'user_id' => 1,
   'role_id' => 1,
]);

DB::table('users_roles')->insert([
   'user_id' => 2,
   'role_id' => 1,
]);

DB::table('users_roles')->insert([
   'user_id' => 3,
   'role_id' => 3,
]);

etc. etc...
```

When I try to run this seeder, I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY' ....
```

Here is the migration of the table:

```
Schema::create('users_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->primary(['user_id','role_id']);
});
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you show the migration for that table?

Comment: Could be that it's got a composite primary key consisting of user_id and role_id and it already has an entry for 1/1

Comment: its probably because you set unique for role_id

Comment: @lagbox please see my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The **PRIMARY KEY** constraint uniquely identifies each record in a table.
>
> Primary keys must contain **UNIQUE** values, and cannot contain **NULL**
> values.
>
> A table can have only **ONE** primary key; and in the table, this primary
> key can consist of single or multiple columns (fields).

You defined 2 primary key :

```
$table->primary(['user_id','role_id']);
```

Change your migration to :

```
Schema::create('users_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id'); // id will be your primary key
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If **role_id** is a primary then the problem is from your seeding data. This means your table schema is not compatible. You should add another column as primary key and remove primary key constraint on **role_id**

Answer (score 0):

check your database. the `role_id` feild may be set as `unique/unsigned` Attributed.
if `role_id` was `unsigned/unique` you should remove it or select none attribute for it.